# Python Metaclass conflict

Tags: python, tkinter, typeerror

i want a button that uses my selectpath function but i cant figure out how to get it working inside a class.
any help ist much appreciated!

i always get this error when i execute it.

> TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases

```
import xlsxwriter
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.messagebox import showerror
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory


class SSLCreator(ttk.Frame, tk.filedialog):
   def __init__(self, container):
       super().__init__(container)
       # field options
       options = {'padx': 5, 'pady': 5}

       # selectPath label
       self.selectPath_label = ttk.Label(self, text='Ordner')
       self.selectPath_label.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=tk.W, **options)
       self.Path = tk.StringVar()

       # selectPath entry
       self.selectPath_entry = ttk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.selectPath)
       self.selectPath_entry.grid(column=1, row=0, **options)
       self.selectPath_entry.focus()

       # selectPath button
       self.selectPath_button = ttk.Button(self, text='Öffnen')
       self.selectPath_button['command'] = self.selectPath
       self.selectPath_button.grid(column=2, row=0, sticky=tk.W, **options)



       # seperator label
       self.seperator_label = ttk.Label(self, text='Seperator')
       self.seperator_label.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=tk.W, **options)
       self.seperator = tk.StringVar()

       # seperator entry
       self.seperator_entry = ttk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.seperator)
       self.seperator_entry.grid(column=1, row=1, **options)
       self.seperator_entry.focus()

       #self.convert_button = ttk.Button(self, text='Convert')
       #self.convert_button['command'] = self.convert
       #self.convert_button.grid(column=2, row=2, sticky=tk.W, **options)


       # result label
       self.result_label = ttk.Label(self)
       self.result_label.grid(row=2, columnspan=3, **options)

       # add padding to the frame and show it
       self.grid(padx=10, pady=10, sticky=tk.NSEW)

   def selectPath(self):
       path_ = self.askdirectory()
       self.Path.set(path_)


class App(tk.Tk):
   def __init__(self):
       super().__init__()
       self.iconbitmap("C:\\Users\\Michael\\Desktop\\icon.ico")
       self.title('SSL Creator')
       self.geometry('300x110')
       self.resizable(False, False)


if __name__ == "__main__":
   app = App()
   SSLCreator(app)
   app.mainloop()
```

Comment: You shouldn't even get a button; I get the error as soon as Python tries to execute the `class` statement.

Comment: You're right...

Comment: It makes no sense to inherit from both `ttk.Frame` and `tk.filedialog` (and I doubt whether that is supported anyway). You should create an internal instance of `tk.filedialog` instead (assuming that's actually needed).

Comment: You don't even need the internal instance. `tk.filedialog` is a module. Just change `path_ = self.askdirectory()` to `path_ = tk.filedialog.askdirectory()` and remove the multiple inheritance.

Comment: Thanks everyone especially @Axe319,  it works now !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root of the problem is that you're inheriting from both `ttk.Frame` and `tk.filedialog`. This simply can't work, you can't inherit from both. Your new class can't both be a frame and a dialog at the same time.

If you want your `SSLCreator` class to have access to a file dialog or its methods, you just need to call the method inside your class.

```
class SSLCreator(ttk.Frame):
   def __init__(self, container):
       super().__init__(container)
       ...

   def selectPath(self):
       path_ = askdirectory()
       self.Path.set(path_)
```